# c# mvc @html.dropdownlistfoe in model.list not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Model

```
public class model{



public List<List> AA {get;set;}


}

public class List{

public string value {get;set;}

}
```

Controller

```
 model.AA[0].value = "MRS.";
```

View

```
@{
  List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

   prelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MR.", Value = "MR." });

   prelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MRS.", Value = "MRS." });

   prelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MISS", Value = "MISS" });

}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AA[0].text,list )
```

---

but view not select value "MRS."

Comment: Isn't the index value (the value you are setting, in this case the variable `Value`)`int`? Also. You are never setting it. You are selecting the first item in the list. Not the variable in that first item.

Comment: I just suppose, In View model.AA[0].value have "MRS." but dropdownlistfor not selected list "MRS."